# Adding A Column To Access Database, Visual Studio Not Updating Column List

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I have a project with a dataset of an access database file.

I opened up the DB file in access, added a column to a table, closed VS2010 & reopened and still it is telling me that the new column is not there in the Data Sources window, even after clicking the refresh button.

I have re-opened Access and confirmed that I am editing the correct file & that the change made is there afterwards still but still no change in VS.

Any ideas what I have done wrong here / how to get VS to update with the correct table details?

Comment: Seconds later after a couple of hours of trying I worked it out!

I needed to open up the Wizard and check the box next to the new column I had added into the DB. Job done :)

Comment: You should look at doing this manually. I used to do it this way, but found that it very quickly became cumbersome and prone to breaking. If you create any calculated columns, you will have to re-create them each time you update your program to the structure of the database.